# Guarantees on estimating a uniform distribution by sampling

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say $H$ is an R.V. which accept only positive integers. Let $X$ be an R.V. uniformly distributed with parameter $H$ and let $X_n$ for $n \geq 1$ be I.I.D copies of $X$.

Define $H_n = |\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}|$ (the number of distinct values observed after $n$ samples).

For $\epsilon > 0$, what is the minimal $n$ such that $P(H=k|H_n=k) > 1 - \epsilon$?

---

I was able to find a recursive formula for $P(H_n=t|H=k)$ by conditioning on $H_{n-1}$:
$P(H_n=t|H=k) =  P(H_{n-1}=t-1|H=k) \frac{k-(t-1)}{k} + P(H_{n-1}=t|H=k) \frac{t}{k}$.

My idea was to use Bayes law, but it requires knowledge about $P(H=k)$, which I don't have.
Any ideas / clues?

Comment: Is it $\mathbb P(H=k\mid H_n=k)$ or $\mathbb P(H_n=k\mid H=k)$ that you are interested in?

Comment: I'm interested in $P(H=k|H_n=k)$.